# call CCMenuiItem function on touchbegan in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

i want to call CCMenuItem on Touch Begin but it calls on touch end how to solve this??

my code is like this

CCMenuItemImage* rld=CCMenuItemImage::itemFromNormalImage("bomb.png","bomb.png",this,menu_selector(MyScene::boom));

i want to call boom function on touchbegin....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your touchBegan

```
CCCallFuncN* functionCall = CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget(this,callfuncN_selector(MyScene::boom));
this->runAction(functionCall);
```

or simply just

```
this->boom(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

**MyLayer.cpp**

MyLayer::MyLayer()

{

this->setTouchEnabled(true);

}

```
   void MyLayer::registerWithTouchDispatcher(void)
 {
     CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this,0);

 }
```

void MyLayer::boom()

{

CCLog("Smart is the new Sexy")

}

```
 void MyLayer::ccTouchesBegan(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
```

CCMenuItemImage* menuItemImage  =  CCMenuItemImage::itemFromNormalImage("bomb.png","bomb.png",
                                           this,menu_selector(MyLayer::boom));

}